# Question related to a differential amplifier: Should one of the inputs be inverted?

Tags: differential, single-supply-op-amp

I have seen differential amplifiers online and I want to know if the differential amplifier would still work if the input signals were half wave signal (positive half cycle.)

[image]

Comment: "*if one of the inputs (V1 or V2) need to be inverted*" Unclear what you mean. An opamp can't accept or output signals beyond its power rails but a diffamp amplifies the difference so if it tries to output a negative value on a positive only supply you need to bias the output so zero output is mid-rail (rather than 0V) but it can never accept a voltage input outside its power rails.

Comment: when you say inverted, do you mean changing V2 to -V2 for example, and the V1 + (-V2)? If that's what you mean, then no. Differential amplifiers do precisely that, amplify the difference between the 2 inputs.

Comment: If all of your signals (input and output) are above zero, you may be able to use a single power supply.  If you need to go negative, then you must provide a negative power supply.

Comment: @NeuroEng, that's what I meant. If  both inputs were positive half cycle, would the differential amplifier still work?

Comment: @Sam I think you got the concept wrong, this amplifier is useful when you, for example, have 2 sensors and you want to measure the difference, so if they have the same value, it will give a zero, meaning no difference, as you correctly mentioned. this is to eliminate "common mode" noise, so signals present on both input meaning they would have been a kind of noise, like electromagnetic radiation present in the area where the wires passed through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologise if I have misunderstood you here, but your question hints to me that you may be having trouble with the concept of "instantaneous value", in context of AC signals, which is very different from a signal's "RMS"*, or "peak" value.

If you don't need me to explain that, then scroll down to the schematic and sample waveforms, which may clarify the behaviour of your circuit given some rectified input. Otherwise, read on.

When somebody says "12 Volts AC", the value "12" in this context is referring to a [kind of*] *average voltage of a signal over an entire cycle*, not its value at any particular instant in time. That is, it is a voltage that rises and falls with time, and at a particular instant can have any value (within certain bounds, of course, related to the number "12", here).

To illustrate, here's a sinusoidal 50Hz, 12V RMS AC voltage:

[image]

I've marked two points in time, \$t_X\$ and \$t_Y\$, and their corresponding *instantaneous* values, \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$. I've also marked two other important parameters, \$V_{RMS}\$ and \$V_{PEAK}\$, which are clearly only very loosely related to \$V_X\$ and \$V_Y\$, in that they define the maximum and minimum possible instantanteous voltage, but nothing else.

The output** of your differential amplifier circuit will be a voltage proportional to the difference of the *instantaneous voltages* \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$. Not peak, or RMS voltage, but the voltages of the inputs at some exact instant in time.

As the input signals (\$V_1\$ or \$V_2\$, or both) rise and fall over time, so will the output of your circuit, such that it always maintains this relationship between \$V_O\$, \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$:

$$ V_O = V_2 (\frac{R_3}{R_2+R_3})(1+\frac{R_f}{R_1}) - V_1 \frac{R_f}{R_1}$$

As you can see neither \$V_{RMS}\$ nor \$V_{PEAK}\$ appear in that equation, because they have little to do with the state of the voltages present at any arbitrarily chosen instant in time.

Here's an implementation of the same circuit, with a couple of simulated input and ouput waveforms:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftGi50.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the second simulation, I'm using a rectified 50Hz sinusoid, but the behaviour of the circuit hasn't changed. Its output is still the difference of the two instantaneous input voltages.

<sub>* By "kind of" I mean that it's not a strict average, it's actually "RMS" or "Root Mean Square", which from a mathematical standpoint is the "standard deviation from the mean". That makes sense, because strictly speaking, any waveform that is symmetrical above and below zero has a mean of zero, which is not very useful information. From an electrical perspective, the RMS amplitude of an AC voltage is the equivalent steady DC voltage that would deliver the same power to some resistance that it's connected across. For sinusoidal signals, \$V_{RMS} = \frac{V_{PEAK}}{\sqrt{2}}\$.</sub>

<sub>** Assuming that the opamp in question is ideal, so we can ignore the common-mode issues that pat's answer correctly refers to, and all other concerns that might arise from real-life imperfections.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an interesting question. Assuming you are asking, what happens if both input signals are positive half cycle. Further, let's assume that you meant both input signals are the exact same phase.  One might intuitively think the output is just zero, since the inputs are the same.

What if we try to simulate this in a spice simulator (with an almost ideal opamp), dual 5v split supply rails, Vcm_DC = 0, and arbitrary Resistor values?

[image]

hmm. The output is not zero. In fact, it's bigger than the input swings with inversion. That's not so obvious. Why? We can look at [the mathematical model for the equation of the weighted difference amplifier](http://www.ittc.ku.edu/%7Ejstiles/412/handouts/2.4%20Differnce%20Amplifiers/Differential%20and%20Common%20Mode%20Gain%20lecture.pdf).

[image]

Well, we know for sure the input difference is zero. So that (left) term goes to zero. But what about the right term? The common mode signal. Well, since this isn't what we normally use with fully differential input signals out of phase, it does not go to zero (even then, it isn't necessarily zero, but small relative to differential gain). Therefore the net gain does not equal zero.

If you need more convincing you can even run the models mathematically in a program like matlab, and see the results are very close to spice. I purposely omitted the vcm signal in the spice sim, to make it less obvious. But you can plot it in spice and see it also matches.

[image]

The slightly less interesting question is what happens if the inputs are both positive half cycles but 180 degrees out of phase. Well, it should be more obvious why the output is not zero. But it's a good exercise to think about why as in the first case.

Comment: Hey Pat, its been long. Per your assumption, both your input voltages are the same. What if the input positive pin has higher voltage than the negative input voltage (same phase and both input signal are positive cycle).

Comment: My first guess would be the input difference is no longer zero so the left term in the equation would now contribute more than zero. I recommend just build the test bench from the first part and run in a simulator to check it out.